# Airflow DAG serialization cache

Tags: python, airflow

I have deployed Airflow 2.2.2 on CeleryExecutor mode. I have built a DAG, which imports classes from a custom package. When I add a new attribute to this imported class, push a new version of my package, re-deploy Airflow with the correct new version package referenced (in a conda env), and add a reference to this new attribute in me DAG, Airflow UI shows an import error, stating that the newly added attribute does not exist in my class.

**What I have already tested:**

- Hard-coding the attribute value in the DAG resulted in the DAG being correctly parsed
- I verified that the correct version of my custom package was installed on the webserver/scheduler containers
- Launching python3.7 on my webserver/scheduler containers (with the conda env activated), and importing the class from my custom package resulted in no  `AttributeError`.
- Re-deploying Airflow after my custom package deployment did not fix anything
- Deleting all entries on `dag_code` and `serialized_dag` metedata tables did not fix the problem

**Conclusions so far**

It seems to me that this is related with the way Airflow 2.x handles dags serialization (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-serialization.html), and that somehow the previous version of the imported class is still cached somewhere.
Any help on this would be much appreciated